# How do you use SQL MINUS statement with multiple returns?

Tags: sql, select

I have a SQL statement that I want to return 6 fields found from a MINUS statement that only compares 1 field from 2 tables.  It works properly when the MINUS statement only returns 1 entry, but errors if it returns more than 1.

```
SELECT DROPPER_ID, EMAIL, ACTIVE, COUNTRY_CD, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PETE.DROPPER   
WHERE DROPPER_ID = (
    SELECT DROPPER_ID FROM PETE.DROPPER WHERE COUNTRY_CD <> 'USA' AND ACTIVE = 1 
    MINUS 
    SELECT DROPPER_ID FROM PETE.DROPPER_COMPARE);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `=`, try using the `IN` statement:

```
SELECT DROPPER_ID, EMAIL, ACTIVE, COUNTRY_CD, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PETE.DROPPER   
WHERE DROPPER_ID IN (
    SELECT DROPPER_ID FROM PETE.DROPPER WHERE COUNTRY_CD <> 'USA' AND ACTIVE = 1 
    MINUS 
    SELECT DROPPER_ID FROM PETE.DROPPER_COMPARE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your where clause: it is currently designed to compare dropper_id with a single value, but that's not actually what you want. To fix it, replace the '=' symbol with the word 'in'. This will tell the WHERE clause to treat the subquery as a tuple or list of values instead of a single value.